# AgoraKit - How to create a grid style video session layout?

Tags: layout, agora.io, videocall

I'm using Agora sdk for video calling feature in my app. I've tried the advance iOS example, and currently able to see the video call between two users.

However my UI needs to show it in grid layout of same size items (maximum 8 video call views)... Like a vertical UICollectionView of equal sized cells. (screenshot below)

I've tried the Advanced video example from here - https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video but couldn't figure out how to make the grids.

Kindly guide me how to do this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a small demo that creates NxN grids of all the video feeds in a chat in this example.

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/Agora-iOS-Swift-Example/blob/248a1d2291060891f2fda92a657c2067d841d964/Agora-iOS-Example/ChannelViewController%2BVideoControl.swift#L108

it just leaves black holes where the other ones should be if there's not a square number of people in the chat, but hopefully it is enough to get you started with repositioning views based on the number of connected users.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd no hopes for a reply on this after so long. I'll definitely check it out